# About `NR==/regex/` matching a pattern

Tags: awk

When I run an `awk` command that has syntax `NR== /regex/`, it gives
unexpected results. The contents of file:

```
cat file

## This is
## a
## b
## c
## end
## e
## f
## g
```

Now I add an empty line at start of file.

```
sed '1 s.^.\n.' file >file2
```

I add another line like this:

```
sed '1 s.^.user288752 is back\n.' file2 >file3
```

Now I run following commands on three files:

```
awk 'NR== /is/, /end/' file

## This is
## a
## b
## c
## end

awk 'NR== /is/, /end/' file2
```

In file2 `awk` matches nothing.

```
awk 'NR== /is/, /end/' file3

## user288752 is back
## 
## This is
## a
## b
## c
## end
```

It appears to me that `is` is matched only if it is present in line 1.
But I haven’t writen `$0 ~ /is/` in this command. And `is` is not equal
to NR. I know `is` in this case is regex(`/is/`) but why `is` should
match NR? What I am missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's look at `NR == /is/`.

This can be rewritten as `NR == ( /is/ )`, which is two boolean tests:

1. `/is/`, which is true if the string `is` is present in the current record (line).
2. `NR == something`, which is true if we're at input line `something`.

In the `awk` language, a boolean with a value of *true* is 1, so if `/is/` is *true*, it will be 1.  The expression `/is/` will be 1 on each line that contains the string `is`. The first file that you have has `is` on the first line, and the second file has `is` on line 2, and in the third file, you have `is` on lines 1 and 3.

```
$ awk '{ printf "NR: %d\t/is/: %d\n", NR, /is/ }' file1
NR: 1   /is/: 1
NR: 2   /is/: 0
NR: 3   /is/: 0
NR: 4   /is/: 0
NR: 5   /is/: 0
NR: 6   /is/: 0
NR: 7   /is/: 0
NR: 8   /is/: 0
$ awk '{ printf "NR: %d\t/is/: %d\n", NR, /is/ }' file2
NR: 1   /is/: 0
NR: 2   /is/: 1
NR: 3   /is/: 0
NR: 4   /is/: 0
NR: 5   /is/: 0
NR: 6   /is/: 0
NR: 7   /is/: 0
NR: 8   /is/: 0
NR: 9   /is/: 0
$ awk '{ printf "NR: %d\t/is/: %d\n", NR, /is/ }' file3
NR: 1   /is/: 1
NR: 2   /is/: 0
NR: 3   /is/: 1
NR: 4   /is/: 0
NR: 5   /is/: 0
NR: 6   /is/: 0
NR: 7   /is/: 0
NR: 8   /is/: 0
NR: 9   /is/: 0
NR: 10  /is/: 0
```

We now know that `/is/` is 1 on certain lines.  This means that the `NR == /is/` test would be *true* if `/is/` is 1 at the same time as `NR` is 1, which it can only be on the first line of input, if anywhere, because `NR` counts lines of input.

Of your three files, the first and last fulfills this criteria, while the second does not.